# Jenkins Upload External Build Artefacts

Tags: jenkins

Does someone know an easy way to add build artefacts to an external-monitor-job (or any other job) in jenkins? The build-in CLI command `set-external-build-result` only allows to add logs.

I want to use it to provide externally built binaries for a downstream test job.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the "external monitor" job type, and let's just talk about artifacts.

In a "free-style" job, and many others (like "Maven" style), you have **Post-Build actions**. One of those is "Archive the Artifacts". This will take whatever files you specify from Workspace, and archive them (i.e. make them available for later use, either manually or for downstream jobs).

The Post-Build "Archive the Artifacts" action doesn't care where they came from (external or not).

So, in your (free-style) job, have some build steps that download whatever external artifacts that you want to Workspace, and then archive them